# Passing dynamic content to a modal box, php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I was originally using a popup window to display dynamic information when the user clicked a button:

```
newwindow=window.open('popup.php?ID=' + id,'name','height=500,width=500');
```

I switched to a [modalbox set up using this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937675/1774546)

To open the modal box I'm using  `openDialog($('#content'));`  where content is a div container.

how can I open the modal box and pass the same php file I was using in the popup window? 
 `'popup.php?ID=' + id`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the content first using AJAX, opening the dialog in the complete callback

```
$('#content').load('popup.php?ID=' + id, function() {
    openDialog($('#content'));
});
```

Docs for [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)